# Makes AxesStyles multiple colors

Tags: plotting, color

I'm aware you can change the axis of a Plot to be one color with [AxesStyles](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesStyle.html), but how do I make it so one axis is more than one color?

Specifically, I would like to make both axes of a 2D plot the colors from `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]`

I have a list of points like the following: `points = {{380, 380}, {380, 390}, ...,  {{780, 780}};`

where each points correlates to a monochromatic light at $\lambda$. I would like to have both the axes correlate to the Visible Spectrum colors.

For example, the color of the axes at around 500 to 550 should be green-ish as that's the color associated with monochromatic light at those values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually add a [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) with appropriate [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) in the [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
points = {#, #} & /@ 
   RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{380, 780}], 20];

ListPlot[
 points,
 Epilog -> Style[{
    AbsoluteThickness@1.5,
    Line[#, VertexColors -> #2] & @@ Transpose@Table[
       {{380, x}, ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][x]}, {x, 
        Subdivide[380, 780, 20]}
       ],
    Line[#, VertexColors -> #2] & @@ Transpose@Table[
       {{x, 380}, ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][x]}, {x, 
        Subdivide[380, 780, 20]}
       ]
    }, Antialiasing -> False
   ],
 AxesOrigin -> {380, 380}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[gradientTicks, gradientAxis]

gradientTicks[rng_, cF_ : "VisibleSpectrum", opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{crange = ColorData[cF, "Range"]}, 
    ReplaceAll[{a_?NumericQ, b_, c_} :>
       Module[{clr = ColorData[cF]@Rescale[a, rng, crange]},
        {a, If[NumberQ @ b, Style[Row[{" ", b, " "}], clr], b], 
         c, Directive[Thick, clr]}]] @
    ReplaceAll[ {FormBox[a : (_String | _?NumericQ), ___] :> a, 
       _FormBox :> Spacer[1]}] @
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, opts, 
        Charting`TicksLength -> {.03, .02}][##]] &

gradientAxis[{a : {_, _}, b : {_, _}}, cF_ : "VisibleSpectrum"] :=
  Line[(1 - #) a + # b & /@ Subdivide[50], 
   VertexColors ->
    (ColorData[cF] /@ Subdivide[## & @@ ColorData[cF, "Range"], 50])]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{380, 750}, {50, 2}];

pr = {{380, 750}, {380, 750}};
sp = .03;

options = {AspectRatio -> 1,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   LabelStyle -> 16,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Opacity[0],
   FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], 
   PlotRange -> pr,
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[sp]};

ListLinePlot[data,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] @ #2 &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> gradientTicks[pr[[1]]],
 Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[7], CapForm["Round"],
  Map[gradientAxis] @ Map[Sort] @ 
  Partition[Tuples[Threaded[{1 - sp, 1 + sp/2}] pr][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], 2, 1, 1]},
 options]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] @ #2 &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> gradientTicks[pr[[1]], "Rainbow"],
 Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[7], CapForm["Round"], 
  Map[gradientAxis[#, "Rainbow"] &] @ Map[Sort] @
  Partition[Tuples[Threaded[{1 - sp, 1 + sp/2}] pr][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], 2, 1, 1]},
  options]
```

[image]

```
PointValuePlot[data -> Join[ConstantArray[{1/2}, Length@data], data, 2],
 {1 ;; 3 -> (PieChart[#[[{1, 1, 1, 1}]], SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/4, 1}, 1}, 
    ChartStyle -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] /@ #[[{3, 2}]])] &)},
 FrameTicks -> gradientTicks[pr[[1]]], 
 Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[7], CapForm["Round"], 
  Map[gradientAxis] @ Map[Sort] @
  Partition[Tuples[Threaded[{1 - sp, 1 + sp/2}] pr][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], 2, 1, 1]},
 options]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

points = {ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][#], {{#, #}}} & /@ 
   RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{380, 780}], 20];

Legended[
 Legended[
  plt = ListPlot[Tooltip /@ points[[All, 2]],
    PlotRange -> {375, 785},
    PlotStyle -> points[[All, 1]],
    Frame -> True],
  Placed[
   BarLegend[{"VisibleSpectrum", {380, 780}},
    LegendMarkerSize -> 188], {1, 0.5}]],
 Placed[
  BarLegend[{"VisibleSpectrum", {380, 780}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300,
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], {0.5, 1}]]
```

[image]