# Color gradient to ticks in a plot

Tags: plotting, color, ticks

Simple question, but I did not find the answer anywhere:

**Is it possible to add a color gradient to the ticks in a plot?**

For example, imagine to have a density plot where some areas are very dark and some very bright. I would like to display whiter ticks in the darker regions and blacker ticks in the brighter regions.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need that? Ticks can be on the frame outside of the plot.

Comment: Because... why not? I mean, I know I can put them outside, but I'd say it's a legitimate question to ask if anybody has an idea on how to implement what I asked.

Comment: closely related Q/A: [Makes AxesStyles multiple colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287570/125)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can, but you will have to roll your own tick generator:

```
ClearAll[gradientTicks]
gradientTicks[tickList_] := gradientTicks[tickList, Scaled[0.02], {White, Black}]
gradientTicks[tickList_, length_] := gradientTicks[tickList, length, {White, Black}]
gradientTicks[tickList_, length_, {lightColor_, darkColor_}] :=
 {#, #, length,
   Directive[
     Thick,
     Blend[{lightColor, darkColor}, Rescale[#, MinMax[tickList]]]
   ]
 } & /@ tickList

ContourPlot[
  x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}],
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
  Ticks -> {
    gradientTicks[Range[0, 2, 0.25], Scaled[0.1], {Yellow, Darker@Blue}], 
    Automatic
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, thank you!

Comment: @Lele I'm glad you liked it! Thank you for the accept as well.